Survival Analysis in R: Using Categorical vs. Continuous Gene Expression with survfit() and coxph()
I'm currently performing a survival analysis based on the expression of a single gene. Here's what I'm doing:
I standardized the gene expression data using scale().
Then, I split the expression values into "high" vs. "low" groups based on the median.
I created a categorical variable called Group ("High" or "Low").
Now, I have a couple of questions:

When using survfit(), I often see it used like this:
surv_fit <- survfit(surv_object ~ Group, data = dpy_surv_data)
Why does survfit() need the categorical Group rather than the continuous gene expression variable? Is it not possible or recommended to use a continuous predictor directly in survfit()?

When fitting a Cox proportional hazards model with coxph(), it seems like I have two options:



Use the categorical variable Group:
cox_fit <- coxph(surv_object ~ Group, data = dpy_surv_data, method = "breslow")

Or use the continuous gene expression values directly:
cox_fit <- coxph(surv_object ~ Expression, data = dpy_surv_data, method = "breslow")


My question is, which approach is better in this context—using the continuous gene expression or the categorized "high vs. low" expression group?
I want to ensure I use the right approach for accurate and interpretable results, especially in the context of assessing risk associated with gene expression levels.
Thanks in advance for your insights!


Why does survfit() need the categorical Group rather than the continuous gene expression variable?

survfit appears to be implementing the Kaplan Meir estimator.  The categorical variable is needed to define strata within which to estimate the product limit estimator.

My question is, which approach is better in this context—using the continuous gene expression or the categorized "high vs. low" expression group?

Generally, it is preferable to keep continuous variables as continuous as opposed to dichotomizing them needlessly. By dichotomizing, you are very likely introducing residual confounding into your estimates. If you are worried that the effect of gene expression may not be linear in the log hazard space, then you could always try a spline to introduce non-linearity.

The survfit() function is designed to provide survival curves corresponding to particular scenarios, either from original grouped data to get Kaplan-Meier curves (formula interface) or from a Cox or parametric survival model to get a set of predicted survival functions. It produces a curve for each scenario. If you use the formula interface, the function needs to use groups to know what separate Kaplan-Meier curves to draw.
If you treated each individual continuous Expression value as a separate "group" with the formula interface for Kaplan-Meier curves, all you would get (without ties in the values) would be multiple survival curves; each would show 100% survival until the event time, when it would drop to 0%. That's not very useful. If you first fit a survival regression model, the survfit() can display more useful survival curves for any specified sets of predictor values.
For any regression model, including a Cox model, it's not generally a good idea to cut a continuous predictor variable into bins. See this page and its links for extensive discussion. That argues against your first model based on Group.
The second model, however, has an assumption that argues against it: that the log-hazard of the outcome is linearly associated with the (scaled) Expression value. That's a pretty strong assumption that is unlikely to be met in practice. For example: did you log-transform the Expression values before scaling, as is often done with gene expression data? A linear association with log-hazard that worked in the log scale wouldn't extend to expression values in the original scale.
That argues for a third way to proceed: a flexible fit of Expression values with a method like a restricted cubic spline. Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies (RMS) explains such flexible fitting in Chapter 2 and illustrates it for Cox model continuous predictors in Chapter 21.
There are a few warnings to heed before you jump ahead to that model.
First, omitting any outcome-associated variable from a Cox model can lead to bias in coefficient estimates. If you are analyzing clinical data as, for example, in cancer survival studies, there's a risk that your gene expression values are simply surrogates for well known clinical variables related to outcome. You could end up spending a lot of effort on your gene, only to find out that you haven't found anything useful except for the associations of the gene with the clinical variables. It makes the most sense to add your Expression as a predictor in addition to already identified outcome predictors.
Second, the more coefficients that you need to fit, the more events you need to have in your data set. See Chapter 4 of RMS. The more flexibly you model the continuous predictor, the more coefficients you need to fit. I think that's why you will often see people dichotomizing continuous predictors at the median: then there's only a single coefficient to fit, and if the association with outcome is very strong you might be able to identify a "significant" result in a small data set. The result will not represent reality very well, however, unless there really is a step-change in hazard at the median value. Furthermore, the median value in your data set probably won't be the same as in others' data sets.
